# Conjecture/observation submission?

Tags: publications, mathematics

I know there are a lot of high-quality journals where I may submit my **serious** research articles. But suppose I have a finding, an observation, a conjecture, a pattern, a poem, an anecdote related to mathematics. Is there a journal that would publish a thing like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Journal of Humanistic Mathematics](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/) seems to be what you are looking for.

> We publish articles that focus mainly on the doing of mathematics, the teaching of mathematics, and the living of mathematics. We also welcome contributions about the state of the mathematical profession (both in research and in education), underrepresentation issues within the world of mathematics, mathematics across national and cultural boundaries, mathematical fiction and poetry, personal reflections that provide insight to the inner workings of the mathematical mind, and other types of writing which may stimulate discussion among our readers. Overall we are a free platform where many different conversations about mathematics are welcome and encouraged.

Comment: Ah, yes. Poetry. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

Many journals have a section devoted to "letters" rather than the normal research papers.

Not the same thing, but scholars often get together at conferences (real and virtual) to bring up such things. If you have the status of Riemann, of course, you can propose questions for which answers are needed.

IIRC the journal of the Mathematical Association of America once had a section for informal things, though I don't know if poems would qualify.

See if [The American Mathematical Monthly](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly) would qualify.